# Splitting a list into sublists in python

Tags: python, list, sublist

I am trying to split a list into sublists if it contains a certain element like `'---'`.

For example, if I have a list:
`['a', 'b', 'c', '----', 'd', 'e']`,  then the resulting list should be

```
                        [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e']]
```

I am new to python and struggling with this, this is the code that I wrote for this problem but its not working

```
 
    start_index = 0
    end_index = 0
    new_list = []
    for character in range(0, len(characters_list)- 1):
        if characters_list[character] == '----':
            end_index = character - 1
            if character == characters_list.index('----'):
                start_index = 0
            else:
                start_index = character + 1
            
            for char in range(start_index, end_index):
                new_list.append(characters_list[char])
```

Comment: Never (99%) of the times iterate lists on indexes - in the remaining 1% of times use enumerate(). This is as simple as `newlist = [[]]`; `for e in charachters_list:` `if e == "----": newlist.append([]) else: newlist[-1].append(e)`. Done

Comment: Yours could also be solved with replacing the last loop by `new_list.append(  characters_list[start:index:end_index+1] )` slicing what you need out of the old list - you simply add elements of the old list into a new list - not into sublists.

Comment: @PatrickArtner thank you so much, it works now. Is it a bad practice to iterate lists on indexes?

Comment: It adds levels of complexity you do not need - so yes. It is bad. There are very few occcasions where you would need the index. Compare yours with what I proposed - which is simpler to understand? better to maintain? Works for your problem?#

Comment: I get it now, thank you. The first solution is definitely easier to understand, I guess I was overcomplicating things. Thank you.

Comment: Your edit made the question worse - keep the example inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). It groups the terms of the list into subslists wrt to the criterium described by `key`-function. Use the `match` (is a boolean value) to filter the sublist.

```
import itertools as it

characters_list = #

new_lst = list(list(i) for match, i in it.groupby(characters_list, lambda p: p == '----') if not match)

print(new_lst)
```

To make clear how the `key` works, here an example of grouping with the opposite condition

```
list(list(i) for match, i in it.groupby(characters_list, lambda p: p != '----') if match)
```

A more intuitive approach

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', '----', 'd', 'e', '----', '1']

out = [[]]
for term in lst:
    if term != '----':
        out[-1].append(term)
    else:
        out.append([])

print(out)
```

Comment: overkill in this case.